# Requesting a code example for mobile website

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my whole webpage available for mobile devices, almost everything on my page is responsive but the text is too small on mobile devices, could anyone help me out with let's say:
HTML:

```
<div class="main">
<section class="page" id="page1">
<div id="background">
<img src="images/background.png" alt="background">
</div>

<h1> </h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
width: 50vw;
position: fixed;
top: 28vw;
left: 50vw;
text-align: center;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
font-size: 2.1vw;
font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
font-style: italic;
color: white;
-webkit-animation: fadein 14s;
-moz-animation: fadein 14s;
-ms-animation: fadein 14s; 
-o-animation: fadein 14s; 
animation: fadein 14s;
}
```

(I have set the text for the H1 tag in a Javascript file)

How can I make the h1 tag so that the text looks big on mobile devices just like on a desktop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [font-size and meta viewport in a responsive design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630633/font-size-and-meta-viewport-in-a-responsive-design)

Comment: `font-size: 2.1vw;` That is new to me lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries). They look like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
```

This says that on screens with a width up to 600px, the font-size of your h1 tag will be 24px. Thereafter, it will be 2.1vw, as defined in your original CSS.

You will also need to add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

to your `<head>`.

It's actually more desirable, instead of using `max-width` in media queries, to use `min-width`. When using `max-width`, you write the CSS for desktop first, and then use media queries to scale the content down. This presents many specificity problems as you are continually overwriting valid CSS - leading to the use of `!important`, which is bad. Using `min-width` means that you write your default CSS for mobile, and then as you scale the browser width up, the media queries kick in as they are now valid. This is called a ["mobile first"](https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-mobile-first-media-queries/) approach.

Comment: I do see some change happening, thank you! could you explain me how you calculate 2.1vw to 24px?

Comment: @Jess great, no problem. I just used a random value, as 2.1vw will depend on the screen size (when the page was rendered). Change 2.1vw in your original CSS to 16px or something (or 32px, just significantly different from 24px) and you will definitely see change.

Comment: If the solution worked for you, could you accept the answer? That will let other people who find this issue in google search or whatever, know what worked. Also I get some rep! Quick overview of that here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work - thanks!

Comment: Basically, a pixel value will always be the same value across any screen size, a viewport value will change as it's dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the viewport properly?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a media query for mobile breakpoints to reset your font-size to something more readable, e.g.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   h1 { font-size: 16px; }
}
```