# What is the best way to calculate the font-size of html element while using the rem?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wanna use the responsive font size by using rem on my website.

As we know, the rem is relative to font-size of the root element. So I should set different font-size of the HTML element in different device.

In my opinion, I think I should use something like a formula by using js/jquery to calculate the font-size and set it to the HTML element. What's more, I am a beginner of front-end and I think the formula should relate to the width of the window but I am not sure about it.

I googled and found almost nothing about this. I wanna know what is the best way to do it? Or if the rem is not the best way for it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px)  {
  body {
    font-size:48px
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 900px)  {
  body {
    font-size:36px
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) and (min-width: 300px)  {
  body {
    font-size:18px
  }
}
```

```html
<body> Test </body>
```

I think it is a better approach to adjust your sizes depending on both height on weight of the screen. Here is a sample which changes the font-size of the body dynamically.

Comment: Well, I have an idea that if I use @media and set the font-size with VW may be will be more smoothly.

Comment: I completely agree with you. Using relative units can make your page look better.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using responsive meta tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

you can read about it on:
[meta tag](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)

[font-size and meta viewport in a responsive design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630633/font-size-and-meta-viewport-in-a-responsive-design)

Comment: But the font-size should be different in different resolution device, right?