# Text size issue on mobile

Tags: html, css

Can someone explain why perceived text size and wrapping change when adding the commented line into the body, below?

To clarify, I want to understand what the layout mechanism is doing in the problem case. I'm not looking for a solution, per se.

This is on mobile (it's fine on desktop).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
    html { background-color: dimgray; }
    body {
      background-color: gray;
      font-family: monospace;
      width: 70ch;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  [== 60 char === === === === === === === === === === === ===]<br>
  [== 60 char === === === === === === === === === === === ===]<br>
  <!-- [== 60 char === === === === === === === === === === === ===] -->
</body>
</html>
```

At first, it renders as expected:

[image]

But if I un-comment the third body line, the text gets big and wraps:

[image]

Just a reminder, this is in mobile view:

[image]

Comment: Are you forgetting the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` inside the `<head>` of your HTML document? It happens... =)

Comment: Thanks! That does fix the problem. What's it do? I'm new to it.

Comment: It's a VIP meta tag that you want to place in ALL your HTML documents. Unlike all other meta tags, this one is special. More details in the answer below.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes. Try to remember this stuff is hard to duplicate-hunt for for us newbies.

Comment: Does the comment automatically added by the system indicate otherwise? Also, you have more badges than I do... Not sure who's the newbie ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML `<meta name="viewport">` tag sets the viewport properties of a webpage, influencing how it will be displayed on different devices. The `width=device-width` makes the width of the webpage follow the screen-width of the device, and `initial-scale=1` sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Reactive Viewport</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Without** the `<meta name="viewport">` tag, the browser will render the webpage as a desktop-scale layout regardless of the device. This often leads to pages that are too wide for mobile devices, requiring the user to zoom and scroll horizontally to see the entire content.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- No viewport meta tag here -->
    <title>Non-Reactive Viewport</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Your content will not be optimized for mobile devices -->
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can either of you answer the question, though, of what the layout mechanism was doing without this tag?

Comment: The [answer on the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29631995/215552) has links to articles which delve deeply into such questions. Reading the specs also helps, but can be a bit ... draining.

Comment: I yield and should have not answered prior to researching first. I confess posting an answer as a followup to the comment was like a muscle spasm. I didn't think before just doing it.

Comment: @Vimes Updated answer with your suggestion. Good idea.